# html newsletter header header not 100%

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, html-email, newsletter

I'm trying to make a newsletter template with Zurb Foundation and my header is not getting 100% width when on a mobile device, it shows this:

[image]

If I remove the images (.gif) - in `<!-- Callout Panel -->`, it works but other stuffs breaks

Can you help me please? Here's my HTML:

```css
/* -------------------------------------
  GLOBAL
------------------------------------- */
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
* { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.collapse {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
 width: 100%!important;
 height: 100%;
}


/* -------------------------------------
  ELEMENTS
------------------------------------- */
a { color: #2BA6CB;}

.btn {
 text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #E03726;
padding: 10px 16px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-right: 5px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
}

p.callout {
 padding:15px;
 background-color:#ECF8FF;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.callout a {
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #2BA6CB;
}

table.social {
/*  padding:15px; */
 background-color: #ebebeb;

}
.social .soc-btn {
 padding: 3px 7px;
 font-size:12px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #FFF;font-weight:bold;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
}
a.fb { background-color: #3B5998!important; }
a.tw { background-color: #1daced!important; }
a.gp { background-color: #DB4A39!important; }
a.ms { background-color: #000!important; }

.sidebar .soc-btn {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
}

/* -------------------------------------
  HEADER
------------------------------------- */
table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

.header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
.header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


/* -------------------------------------
  BODY
------------------------------------- */
table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


/* -------------------------------------
  FOOTER
------------------------------------- */
table.footer-wrap { width: 100%; clear:both!important;
}
.footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
.footer-wrap .container td.content p {
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight: bold;

}


/* -------------------------------------
  TYPOGRAPHY
------------------------------------- */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
}
h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small { font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; }

h1 {font-weight: 550;font-size: 22px;}
h2 { font-weight: 600;font-size: 13px; font-style: italic;color: #FEC52C;}
h3 { font-weight:500; font-size: 27px;}
h4 { font-weight:500; font-size: 16px;}
h5 { font-weight:900; font-size: 17px;}
h6 { font-weight:900; font-size: 36px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#fff;}

.collapse { margin:0!important;}

p, ul {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:1.6;
}
p.lead { font-size:17px; }
p.last { margin-bottom:0px;}

ul li {
 margin-left:5px;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

/* -------------------------------------
  SIDEBAR
------------------------------------- */
ul.sidebar {
 background:#ebebeb;
 display:block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul.sidebar li { display: block; margin:0;}
ul.sidebar li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #666;
 padding:10px 16px;
/*  font-weight:bold; */
 margin-right:10px;
/*  text-align:center; */
 cursor:pointer;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
 border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 display:block;
 margin:0;
}
ul.sidebar li a.last { border-bottom-width:0px;}
ul.sidebar li a h1,ul.sidebar li a h2,ul.sidebar li a h3,ul.sidebar li a h4,ul.sidebar li a h5,ul.sidebar li a h6,ul.sidebar li a p { margin-bottom:0!important;}



/* ---------------------------------------------------
  RESPONSIVENESS
  Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.
------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
.container {
 display:block!important;
 max-width:600px!important;
 margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
 clear:both!important;
}

/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
.content {
 padding:15px;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
}

/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
.content table { width: 100%; }


/* Odds and ends */
.column {
 width: 300px;
 float:left;
}
.column tr td { padding: 15px; }
.column-wrap {
 padding:0!important;
 margin:0 auto;
 max-width:600px!important;
}
.column table { width:100%;}
.social .column {
 width: 280px;
 min-width: 279px;
 float:left;
}

/* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
.clear { display: block; clear: both; }


/* -------------------------------------------
  PHONE
  For clients that support media queries.
  Nothing fancy.
-------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

 div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

 table.social div[class="column"] {
  width:auto!important;
 }

}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#000">
 <tr>
  <td class="header container" align="">

   <!-- /content -->
   <div class="content">
    <table bgcolor="#000" >
     <tr>

      <td align="left"><h6 class="collapse">Newsletter</h6><h2 class="collapse">Delivering the latest ENTERPRISE MOBILITY news, analysis &amp; insight</h2></td>
      <td align="right"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6d/d3/f0/6dd3f01fd9f681920431a9ed9241a638.png" width="60" height="59" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div><!-- /content -->

  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table><!-- /HEADER -->

<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap" bgcolor="">
 <tr>
  <td class="container" align="" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

   <!-- content -->
   <div class="content">
    <table>
     <tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#E8E8E8" style="padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; display:block; max-width:575px; Margin:0 auto; clear:both;">
         <h1>Featured This Week</h1>
         <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/news/here%E2%80%99s-why-ready-made-apps-are-the-future">Here’s Why Ready-Made Apps Are The Future</a></h4>

    <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->
         <p><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/news/here%E2%80%99s-why-ready-made-apps-are-the-future"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/e0/90/68e090fbdddf572bb041c2409691998c.jpg" width="600" height="150" border="0"></a></p>
         <!-- /hero -->

         <p style="Margin-bottom: 15px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">IT admins aren’t shy about the wasted time and money being thrown at enterprise mobile apps. That’s why so many companies are heading for out-of-the-box products to make workflows easier. </p>
         <a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/news/here%E2%80%99s-why-ready-made-apps-are-the-future" class="btn">Read more »</a> </td>
     </tr>
            </tbody></table>
   </div><!-- /content -->

   <div class="content">

    <table bgcolor="">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 10px 13px 0px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/managing-the-masses-device-control-eliminates"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/19/94/431994fbcecd62b5f004ae9cb620763a.jpg" width="120" height="115" border="0"></a></td>
        <td>
       <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/managing-the-masses-device-control-eliminates">Managing The Masses: Device Control Eliminates Chaos</a></h4>
       <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Enterprises are flush with endpoints that require proper management. Learn how companies like National Geographic and Hudl are protecting devices and data from a single dashboard.</p>
        <a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/managing-the-masses-device-control-eliminates" class="btn">Read more »</a>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>

   </div>

   <div class="content">

    <table bgcolor="">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:13px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/week-in-the-life-lisa-tuttle-ciso-spx-corporation"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ec/be/57/ecbe577538fbfda84f24193d6a538359.jpg" width="120" height="115" border="0"></a></td>
       <td>
        <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/week-in-the-life-lisa-tuttle-ciso-spx-corporation">Week In The Life: CISO Lisa Tuttle</a></h4>
       <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">What’s it like to defend the enterprise from constant threats while trying to progress the business? SPX Corporation’s CISO Lisa Tuttle shares her weekly to-do list with Enterprise Mobility Exchange.</p>
        <a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/week-in-the-life-lisa-tuttle-ciso-spx-corporation" class="btn">Read more »</a>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </div>

   <div class="content">

    <table bgcolor="">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:13px;"><a href="https://event.on24.com/wcc/r/1523739/30E5544664FCFD831E27533A8317EC5C?partnerref=NLFeature-11-07-17"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f2/cf/cc/f2cfcce72fef531c96f214ff41c863af.jpg" width="120" height="115" border="0"></a></td>
       <td>
        <h4><a href="https://event.on24.com/wcc/r/1523739/30E5544664FCFD831E27533A8317EC5C?partnerref=NLFeature-11-07-17">Webinar: Extend The Back-Office With Mobile Micro Apps</a></h4>
       <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Sarah Hemmerling of KVC Health Systems will share how her company embarked on a strategic initiative to make its business apps quick and easy to use by implementing task-based mobile micro apps.</p>
        <a href="https://event.on24.com/wcc/r/1523739/30E5544664FCFD831E27533A8317EC5C?partnerref=NLFeature-11-07-17" class="btn">Register now! »</a>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td align="center" style="padding: 5px 5px 15px 5px;">

   <!-- Callout Panel -->
   <a href="https://event.on24.com/wcc/r/1523739/30E5544664FCFD831E27533A8317EC5C?partnerref=NLBannerAd-11-07-17">
   <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3c/2a/41/3c2a41a795c7f779110cc2dd20099370.gif" alt="" width="575" height="114" border="1" align="center" style="max-width:575px; padding-bottom: 15; display: inline !important; vertical-align: center;"></a>
   <a href="https://event.on24.com/wcc/r/1523739/30E5544664FCFD831E27533A8317EC5C?partnerref=NLBannerAd-11-07-17"></a>       <!-- /callout panel --></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content">
    <table bgcolor="#cccccc" style="padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;">
     <tbody><tr height="20">
      <td align="left"><h1 class="collapse">Top Recent Reports &amp; Analysis</h1></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/machine-machine/white-papers/the-iot-ecosystem-strategic-management-leads-to"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/3a/81/153a81f7246f3e03926f681ff2b99096.gif" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/machine-machine/white-papers/the-iot-ecosystem-strategic-management-leads-to"><strong>How To Launch IoT Products Successfully</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">IoT applications and services now are moving from cautious, limited volume trials and pilot projects into mainstream, mass-market deployments. How those individual devices and networks are launched, however, is what makes the difference between IoT success or failure.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/new-app-world-turnkey-solutions-are-enabling"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e7/c7/1f/e7c71f1ef359e6b6801edf9aa98126cf.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/new-app-world-turnkey-solutions-are-enabling"><strong>New App World: Turnkey Solutions Enable Businesses</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">The need for functional enterprise applications to handle daily work tasks has exceeded the number of capable developers and designers, so new solutions are disrupting development cycles.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/scaling-enterprise-mobility-with-mam-mdm"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5c/86/4b/5c864bb590372887b56cc4440b4dc309.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/scaling-enterprise-mobility-with-mam-mdm"><strong>Case Study: MAM Finds Success At TD Bank</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">What enterprises don’t yet realize is MAM and MDM can seamlessly integrate, providing cutting edge technology and security at the same time. TD Bank and Ace Hardware provide proof.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/the-top-5-enterprise-mobility-challenges"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/de/24/3e/de243ebfab7242a3c463688923bcfb46.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-app-platforms/white-papers/the-top-5-enterprise-mobility-challenges"><strong>The Top 5 Enterprise Mobility Challenges</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Enterprises are racing to integrate third-party services to apps on their own to gain productivity, collaboration, and operational advantages. With these rapid changes in mobility, gaps and challenges are emerging quickly.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/a-look-inside-the-well-oiled-mobility-machine"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/51/af/6f51af5e86a2b793d079ae322361268c.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/a-look-inside-the-well-oiled-mobility-machine"><strong>A Look Inside The Well-Oiled Mobility Machine</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">The rise of mobile growth has brought a wide array of changes to industries across the world. Digital transformation is altering the landscape of business at every level. Not only that, but it’s speeding up.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/the-current-state-of-mobile-malware"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b3/0f/1e/b30f1e7856938670db9812ac860fadf4.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/the-current-state-of-mobile-malware"><strong>The Current State of Mobile Malware</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Malware is one of the hottest topics in enterprise mobile security, and yet, many still fail to fully comprehend the risk. Mobile malware’s proliferation continues to escalate and cause chaos in the company setting.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/full-life-cycle-mobile-management-strategies"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/59/21/ec/5921ec595d1f4b61ce4b3dbddd80d779.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-managed-mobility/white-papers/full-life-cycle-mobile-management-strategies"><strong>Full Life Cycle: Mobile Management Strategies</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">From handwritten letters to the latest trending tweets, communication has always driven industry. That is truer than ever, when each business unit utilizing mobility to stay connected.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/cyber-security-in-the-iot-era-what-you-need-to"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c2/9a/f5/c29af50e76b4257e71610380d1f5d325.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/eme-security/white-papers/cyber-security-in-the-iot-era-what-you-need-to"><strong>Cybersecurity In The IoT Era: What You Need To Know</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Security experts have long warned of the rising threats to business continuity in the Internet of Things (IoT) era. Still, many were shocked by a widespread internet outage in which thousands of personal devices were hijacked.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">
    <tbody><tr>
     <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:5px;"><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/devices-ruggedized/white-papers/expanding-the-enterprise-deploying-rugged-devices"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bf/c3/0f/bfc30fdca04d5a1498f73dac3fba75bf.jpg" width="120" height="120" border="0"></a></td>
     <td>
      <h4><a href="https://www.enterprisemobilityexchange.com/devices-ruggedized/white-papers/expanding-the-enterprise-deploying-rugged-devices"><strong>Expanding the Enterprise: Deploying Rugged Devices</strong></a></h4>
      <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Today's enterprises are putting large percentages of their spending budget toward digital transformation, but often not seeing enough return on the investment as mobile devices are constantly in need of expensive updates, repairs, or replacements.</p>
      <!--<a class="btn">Read more &raquo;</a><-->

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content"><table bgcolor="">

   <!-- Callout Panel -->
   <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bc/3d/be/bc3dbe327441483469484d230b610d6c.png" alt="" width="575" height="114" border="1" align="center" style="max-width:575px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;"> <a href="#"></a>       <!-- /callout panel --></td>

    </tr>
   </tbody></table></div>

   <div class="content">
    <table bgcolor="">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td>

       <!-- social & contact -->
       <table bgcolor="" class="social" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
         <td height="110">

          <!--- column 1 -->
          <div class="column">
          <table bgcolor="" cellpadding="" align="left">
          <tbody><tr>
           <td width="225">
           <h5 class="">Connect with Us!</h5>
              <p class="">
               <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/groups/128705"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-linkedin-48.png" width="24" class=""></a>
               <a href="https://twitter.com/mobilityxchange"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-twitter-48.png" height="24" width="24" class=""></a>
               <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc2M4wbfs3dw13WeUDona3g"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-youtube-48.png" height="24" width="24" class=""></a>
              </p>
             </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table><!-- /column 1 -->
          </div>

          <!--- column 2 -->
          <div class="column">
           <table bgcolor="" cellpadding="" align="left">
          <tbody><tr>
           <td width="300">

            <h5 class="">We'd love to hear from you!</h5>
            <p style="Margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size:14px; line-height:1.6;">Send us feedback at: <strong><a href="emailto:news@enterprisemobilityexchange.com">news@enterprisemobilityexchange.com</a></strong></p>

           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody></table><!-- /column 2 -->
          </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody></table><!-- /social & contact -->

      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
   </div>
</body>
```

```
> https://jsfiddle.net/a5g42wym/
```

Comment: Its working! no issues

Comment: Mayor problem could also be for newsletter that you are using external `CSS` file or separate `CSS` code in `<style>` tag, because email clients will only read inline style.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `!important` to this class

`table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}`

I've seen cases before where Android clients will wrap to 100% of the content rather than expand to 100%.